# Cannot compare year with different table fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to extract a `coach` that have a career that start from  a specific `year` for a specific `team.id`, these are the data sample:

competition_seasons

```
| id | competition_id | season_id | name 
  22         48            14214    2017/2018
```

coach_career

```
| coach_id | team_id | start        | end
   223496      69       2018-07-01    NULL
   223496     4345      2011-10-01    2015-06-01
   223496    15376      2011-02-01    2011-10-01
```

In this case I need to extract the career of the `coach` that start in the `year` 2018 contained in `season.name` (2017/2018), of the `team.id` = 69.

For achieve this, I tried this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM coach_career cr
INNER JOIN coach c ON c.id = cr.coach_id
INNER JOIN competition_seasons s ON s.id = 22
WHERE cr.team_id = 69
AND `start` LIKE concat('%', cast(extract(year from s.name) as char(100)), '%')
```

but this will return an empty result, I guess I commit some mistake on year extraction, someone know how to achieve this?

NB: The table `coach` is the master table of `coach_career`, and simply contains the information of the person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query.

Because you wnat to use colnum with `like`, so `||` instead of `concat`.

then move start`LIKE '%' || s.name || '%'` condition to `ON` of `JOIN`, because `INNER JOIN competition_seasons s ON s.id = 22` will return all play.

```
SELECT *
FROM coach_career cr
INNER JOIN coach c ON c.id = cr.coach_id
INNER JOIN competition_seasons s ON `start` LIKE '%' || s.name || '%'
WHERE  
  s.id = 22 
and 
  cr.team_id = 69
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03d275/14)

**[Results]**:

```
| coach_id | team_id |      start |    end | id | competition_id | season_id |      name |
|----------|---------|------------|--------|----|----------------|-----------|-----------|
|   223496 |      69 | 2018-07-01 | (null) | 22 |             48 |     14214 | 2017/2018 |
```

Comment: just a question: why you added the `||` between `s.name` I never encountered this syntax before

Answer (score 1):

You could try below code. It uses [`locate()`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-locate-function.php) function to check wether year of starting career is included within `name` of a season.

Sample data:

```
create table competition_seasons(id int, competition_id int, season_id int, name varchar(10));
insert into competition_seasons values (22, 48, 14214, '2017/2018');
create table coach_career(coach_id int, team_id int, `start` date, `end` date);
insert into coach_career values
(223496, 69, '2018-07-01', NULL),
(223496, 4345, '2011-10-01', '2015-06-01'),
(223496, 15376, '2011-02-01', '2011-10-01');
```

T-SQL:

```
select * from coach_career cc
where exists(select 1 from competition_seasons
             where locate(year(cc.start), name) > 0);
```